# Slow wifi when bt on or bt device (headset) connected

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, bluetooth

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 and wifi is slow when bt on or when bt device connected.

Google speed test bt on & device connected: under 1 Mbps. 
Google speed test bt on: under 40 Mbps. 
Google speed test bt off: ~100 Mbps.

Don't know how to debug this problem.

I've already changed the wi-fi powersave to 2 on `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 08)
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M] (rev a1)
08:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

**lspci -k -s 06:00.0**

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

**systemctl | grep -i blue**

```
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb1-1\x2d1-1\x2d1.6-1\x2d1.6:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device loaded active     plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/bluetooth/hci0
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                                 loaded active     plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0                                       
  bluetooth.service                                                                           loaded active     running   Bluetooth service                                                           
  bluetooth.target                                                                            loaded active     active    Bluetooth
```

**dmesg | grep -i blue**

```
[   15.430927] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   15.430953] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.430958] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.430959] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.430962] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   30.656386] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   30.656387] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   30.656390] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   76.132234] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   76.132240] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   76.132245] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

**rfkill list all**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:002a Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:0036 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:64af Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I had this problem when the Bluetooth dongle did not play well with the wireless dongle, I changed the Bluetooth dongle for a new one rev 4 and it is fine now. Just an idea.

Comment: Bit of a long shot but it could just be interference, try going to your router settings and changing the wifi band between 2.4ghz and 5ghz to see if that helps.

Comment: I'm gonna try your suggestions, thank you.